# EJB method call from itself: does the container have influence on it?

Tags: java, ejb

I would like to know if the EJB container has impact on method calls withing an EJB. I'm not sure if `@TransactionAttributes` annotations or any  other annotation has effect in this case or not. If it has, how it is implemented in the container?

```
@Stateless
public class MyBean {   

  public void doSomething() {
    // logic
    doSomethingElse();
    // logic
  }

  @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.NOT_SUPORTED)
  public void doSomethingElse() {
    // logic
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plain java call to doSomethingElse() is not handled by the container. If you want to make an "EJB-call" then you should use [SessionContext.getBusinessMethod(...)](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/SessionContext.html#getBusinessObject(java.lang.Class)):

```
sessionContext.getBusinessObject(MyBean.class).doSomethingElse();
```

Comment: I have the same question, can you tell me what is sessionContext, and how to get that variable ?

Comment: There are few ways how to get it: 
1) using resource injection - @Resource private SessionContext sctx; 
2) using JNDI - 
InitialContext ic = new InitialContext();
sctxLookup = (SessionContext)ic.lookup("java:comp/EJBContext");